# forloop counter with htmx django

Tags: django, htmx

By following tutorials, I've managed to make a form which adds order items with htmx. Each new order item is a div row, not a table row. I also have a forloop counter for each row, but after a new order item is added, the counter doesn't update dynamically, only after the page refresh.

The related (I think) code:

order-create-update.html:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<style>
  .orderitem-form {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px">
    {% include 'orders/order_form_full.html' %}

<hr>   
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px">
      <div class="col-1" style="font-weight: bold">Item #</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="font-weight: bold">Material Category</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="font-weight: bold">Material Subcategory</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="font-weight: bold">Material</div>
      <div class="col-1" style="font-weight: bold">Quantity</div>
      <div class="col-1" style="font-weight: bold">Price/Unit</div>  
      <div class="col-1" style="font-weight: bold">Action</div>  
  </div>

  {% for orderitem in object.get_orderitems_children %} 
  {% include "orders/order_item_inline.html" with object=orderitem %}  
  {% endfor %}

  {% if new_orderitem_url %}  
  <div id="orderitem-create"></div>  
  {% endif %}
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" hx-get="{{ new_orderitem_url }}" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#orderitem-create" hx-swap="beforeend">Add order item</button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

order_item_inline.html:

```
<div id="orderitem-{{ object.id }}">
    <div class="row mt-1">        
        <div class="col-1">{{ forloop.counter }}</div>        
        <div class="col-2">{{ object.material_category }}</div>
        <div class="col-2">{{ object.material_subcategory }}</div>
        <div class="col-4">{{ object.material }}</div>
        <div class="col-1">{{ object.quantity_ordered }}</div>
        <div class="col-1">{{ object.material.price }}</div>  
        <div class="col-1"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" hx-trigger="click" hx-get="{{ object.get_hx_edit_url }}" hx-target="#orderitem-{{ object.id }}">Edit</button>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Something is missing, but after looking for the answer for a few days, I can't figure it out...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you. This is beyond my expertise. Shouldn't there be a more simple way to add a counter to, let's say, the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hx-vals](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/) to dynamically add existing row counter as a GET param and from that calculate the new number.
You would have to use js version to dynamically calculate number of rows which shouldn't be difficult with vanilla js.

Although you will get into problems, considering you would also like to remove rows in the future. You may be forced to re-generate all items each time you add new one.